# Compact quasi-Einstein metric with constant scalar curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, curvature

**Introduction**:

Let $(M^n,g)$ be Riemannian manifold and consider a smooth function $f:M\to\left(0,+\infty\right)$.

The $m$-Bakry--Emery--Ricci tensor is defined as
$$
Ric_f^m:=Ric+\nabla^2f-\frac{1}{m}df\otimes df,\quad 0< m\leq \infty,
$$
where $Ric$ is the $(0,2)$ Ricci tensor of $(M,g)$ and $\nabla^2$ is the Hessian.

A triple $(M,g,f)$ is called $m$-quasi Einstein if there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
Ric_f^m=\lambda g\label{eq: quasi E}.
\end{equation}

When $0<m<\infty$ one can consider $u=e^{-f/m}$ and using the relations ($\nabla u$ is the gradient of $u$)
\begin{align*}
\nabla u&=-\frac{1}{m}e^{-f/m}\nabla f\\
\frac{m}{u}\nabla^2 u&=-\nabla^2 f+\frac{1}{m} df\otimes df,
\end{align*}
one sees
\begin{equation}
Ric_f^m=\lambda g\Longleftrightarrow Ric-\frac{m}{u}\nabla^2 u=\lambda g.
\end{equation}
Taking the trace of the last relation one obtains
\begin{equation}
\Delta u=\frac{u}{m}(S-\lambda n)
\end{equation}
where $S$ is the scalar curvature of $(M,g)$

**I am trying to understand**:

In "[Rigidity of quasi-Einstein metrics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224510000720)", the authors claim that since $u>0$, the last above equation immediately implies (Proposition 2.1):

> A compact quasi-Einstein metric with constant scalar curvature is
>   trivial, i.e, $f$ is constant.

(1) I would like to know a justification for that claim.

*I only realized that under the condition that the scalar curvature $S$ is constant then $u=e^{-f/m}$ must be an eigenfunction of the Laplacian with eigenvalue $\frac{S-\lambda n}{m}$ then I cannot conclude anymore. I don't know if a "known" result is needed*.

(2) I would like to list/collect other sufficient conditions to conclude that a $m$-quasi Einstein metric is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The key is that $u$ is positive (as the exponential of something).  As you already noted, $u$ is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian.  But the strong maximum principle implies that (on a compact manifold) the only positive eigenfunctions of the Laplacian are the positive constants.

(2) The literature now contains far more sufficient conditions for the triviality of an $m$-quasi Einstein metric than I can keep track of.  If you have access to MathSciNet, you can [find](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=2784291&loc=refcit) [all](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?revcit=2784291&loc=revcit) published papers which cite our paper, many of which contain some new sufficient condition.  You can also use [Google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=8931578892091976100&as_sdt=5) for a similar purpose.  As far as I know, only in dimensions one or two do we know exactly which Riemannian manifolds are $m$-quasi-Einstein; see [this article](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/cag/content/vols/0020/0002/a003/) of He, Petersen and Wylie.